# How to Center a UIButton in a TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to make my custom button to center in tableView Cell, because It feels like the button somehow offset to the left (I think it's because of the frame for accessory type.
I have tried using the didselectrowatindexpath but I feel like I want to do it with UIButton. Do you have any idea how to make my button in tableviewcell center? I have tried using self.view.center but it doesn't work. here's the code:

```
    self.buatAkunBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectInset(self.buatAkunBtnCell.contentView.bounds, 0, 0))
    self.buatAkunBtn.setTitle("Masuk", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.buatAkunBtn.setTitleColor(acehBusColor, forState: .Normal)
    self.buatAkunBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("btncreateAccTapped:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.buatAkunBtnCell.addSubview(self.buatAkunBtn)
```

Here's the image from which caused by the code above:
[image: image offset to the left not centralised]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**METHOD 0:**

If you absolutely want to use code. Here is how I would solve your case:

```
self.buatAkunBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectInset(self.buatAkunBtnCell.contentView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 30, dy: 0), 0, 0))
self.buatAkunBtn.setTitle("Masuk", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.buatAkunBtn.setTitleColor(acehBusColor, forState: .Normal)
self.buatAkunBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("btncreateAccTapped:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
self.buatAkunBtnCell.addSubview(self.buatAkunBtn)
```

---

Or you can use the Interface builder which would be much simpler and elegant.

**METHOD 1:**

1) Click on your UIButton.

2) Add constraints relative to Cell 0 to left, 0 to right.

[image]

3) Your UIButton is now centered.

**METHOD 2 (recommended):**

1) Click on your UIButton.

2) Ctrl drag from your button to your cell.

[image]

3) Select "center horizontally in container".

[image]

**METHOD 3 (recommended):**

1) Click on your UIButton.

2) Click on the alignment constraint icon at the bottom right.

3) Click on the checkbox: "center horizontally in container"

[image]

Comment: You're awesome, dude! But I didn't make my button on storyboard, but programatically, and the button isn't on itself but inside the table view cell. Could you show me the pseudocode? THanks.

Comment: I could. But why not create the button on the stroryboard ? There is no need to create it programmatically.Please tell me why first :) Because the interface builder would be a much more elegant solution. And if you absolutely need to use code on your button, make an IBOutlet.

Comment: I know, here's my case. I made a static table view cell where all the text fields and a button inside the table view cell. The Table view cell I've made is programatically so on the main board, it's just a prototype view cell where all the text field and button doesn't exist yet. That's what happened. Thanks.

Comment: It won't work. :(( 
CGRectMake says cannot assign value to UIButton.
and the translateautoresizing says UIButton has no member setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Comment: Never say "it won't work", it's better to tell us what error you got :) so we may help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111301/discussion-between-chronycles-and-coder1000).